# How to call a stored procedure in oracle from shell

Tags: oracle, shell

I have installed cygwin and i have Oracle 10 g now i want to connect database from shell.can anyone help me??

```
   SQL> create or replace procedure get_area
2 (n_length in number,
3 n_width in number,
4 n_area out number)
5 as
6 begin
7 n_area := n_length*n_width;
8 end get_area;
9 /
```

This is my procedure  i have created in oracle 10g.I want to call the get_area from shell

i am doing this to start that process 
subho@subho-PC ~$ #!/bin/csh-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just do it like this

```
sqlplus login/pass @get_area.sql
```

where get_area.sql contains your SQL code

the last detail is to put an `exit;` at the end of the script oftherwise you will stay on the `SQL >` prompt

Comment: please elaborate i can not understand

Comment: i changed my explanation ; hope this could help

Comment: declare
 n_area number :=0;
 begin
 get_area(10,20,n_area);
 dbms_output.put_line('Area '||n_area);
 end; but it show PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. but not output is coming